# Kotlin: checking result inside lambda

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I have lambda expression:

```
repository!!.getAllByDateForUser(userId, date)
                .map { ... }
                .flatMap { ... }
```

and so on. I need to check data after executing first row. For example, check that result list is not empty. And if it's empty, return other object or throw exception. If it is not empty, I run expression further. But I want to check it within expression.

Please, advice, how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `also()` to do additional operations on an object, while returning itself:

Since `also()` is an inline function, Kotlin allows you to use *non-local returns* to exit the current function from within the lambda.

```
repository!!.getAllByDateForUser(userId, date)
    .map { ... }
    .also { list ->
        if (list.isEmpty())
            return xy // exit function (not only lambda)
    }
    .flatMap { ... }
```

Of course, you can do that on a single line per chaining call, if you prefer this style:

```
repository!!.getAllByDateForUser(userId, date)
    .map { ... }
    .also { if (it.isEmpty()) return xy }
    .flatMap { ... }
```